# How to count number of time the user use my app?

Tags: iphone

I want to count number of time the user use my app. eg: a user use my app and i can to count number of time that user use my app.
Thanks you so much!

Comment: You've given no details on where you want to record this information.  Locally, remotely?

Answer (score 1):

Use a stats site/lib like Flurry to get data on how users use your app on aggregate.

Comment: I am not very clear with your comments. Please give me a more detailed explanation. Thanks you!

Comment: [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com) is like Google Analytics for mobile applications. With a bit of configuration you can find out how people use your app, and for how long. You can also get statistics on how many people are using your app. Hope this helps, but see their website for more details. It's free to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with `NSUserDefaults`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger launchCount = [prefs integerForKey:@"launchCount"];
    launchCount++;
    [prefs setInteger:launchCount  forKey:@"launchCount"];  

// YOUR CODE HERE

}
```

Now just read the value of `launchCount` whenever you like to determine the number of times the user has launched your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want save time count, use a `NSUserDefaults`.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

**Example here**: http://www.albertopasca.it/whiletrue/

In this way you can save anithink to device storage and load as you want.

Every `applicationDidFinishLaunching` use `counter++` and save to disk.

---

For better stats, on `willApplicationTerminate` send data to mail / server / etc...

hope this helps.